# Name Not Found Even if Exists in the JSON file Updated

Tags: json, directory, runtime-error, libgdx, auto-update

There is a runtime error which keeps telling me that the name have not been found. Take a look at this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Name 'lame' was not found.
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Name 'lame' was not found.
    at aurelienribon.bodyeditor.BodyEditorLoader.attachFixture(BodyEditorLoader.java:79)
    at com.bodapps.shootme.physics.controller.BodyPhysicsSettings.setGoalPostBody(BodyPhysicsSettings.java:32)
    at com.bodapps.shootme.view.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:273)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:59)
    at com.bodapps.shootme.Start.create(Start.java:11)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:125)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)
```

This error came from this code. Take a look and see comment on code below.

```
    goalPost1 = wc.getWorld().createBody(def1);
    goalPost1.setActive(true);
    goalPost1.setGravityScale(0);
    goalPostLoader1.attachFixture(goalPost1, "lame", fixtures1, 5); // --> Under the same JSON filenamename and added and updated this name "lame." However, this is where it stops here.

    goalPost2 = wc.getWorld().createBody(def2);
    goalPost2.setActive(true);
    goalPost2.setGravityScale(0);
    goalPostLoader2.attachFixture(goalPost2, "soccer ball", fixtures2, 5); // --> This name, also in the same JSON filename. Even it has a space, it should be worked too.
```

The JSON filename "ball physics.json" and this is where I took it from the **Physics Body Editor** engine.

[image]

Here's the code from the JSON file.

```
{
"rigidBodies":
[
    {
        "name":"soccer ball",
        "imagePath":"../images/soccer ball.png",
        "origin":{"x":0,"y":0},"polygons":[],
        "circles":[{"cx":0.5,"cy":0.5,"r":0.4756574332714081}],
        "shapes":[{"type":"CIRCLE","vertices":[{"x":0.5,"y":0.5},{"x":0.5250000357627869,"y":0.02500000037252903}]}]
    },

    {
        "name":"lame",
        "imagePath":null,
        "origin":{"x":0,"y":0},
        "polygons":[[{"x":0.625,"y":0.05000000074505806},{"x":0.625,"y":0.949999988079071},{"x":0.3499999940395355,"y":0.949999988079071},{"x":0.3499999940395355,"y":0.05000000074505806}]],
        "circles":[],
        "shapes":[{"type":"POLYGON","vertices":[{"x":0.3499999940395355,"y":0.05000000074505806},{"x":0.3499999940395355,"y":0.949999988079071},{"x":0.625,"y":0.949999988079071},{"x":0.625,"y":0.05000000074505806}]}]
    }
],

"dynamicObjects":[]
}
```

I registered the name "**lame**" after editing from the Physics Body Editor that saves as JSON file. Unfortunatelly, the programming software cheats on me even if I'm correct. Please, help me fix it as soon as possible.

**Updated question! (As of 4/11/2013)**

I wonder if the assets in the Desktop starter project folder matches with or it has the same and directory with the Android starter project folder? If that case, does the updating files added in the assets folder in project folder (Android starter) automatically updates in the Desktop starter project folder or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the problem in updating at the Desktop starter project folder, the image files and JSON file was **not directly from Android's assests automatically copied to Desktop's assets**! In case of this problem, I have to manually copy it. It's the only best thing I could ever do. From the Android assets folder, select the specified file and directory (folder) and copy it to the assets folder in Desktop. Make sure that the directory and filename is correct.